# Timer BroadcastReceiver - onReceive at 2pm or after 44min?

Tags: java, android, timer, broadcastreceiver

I would like to register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in the Android manifest, or in code if necessary, that would send a broadcast to my application based on time.

e.g. i would like my **onReceive to be called time-dependently by the Android OS**

- at say a regular interval
- or at a given time of day
- or once after a specific amount of time has lapsed (say after 44 minutes from some call in my application)

How might that be possible *without leaving my app running in the background all the time* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See AlarmManager and android.intent.action.TIME_TICK

Comment: could you be a bit more specific please - i understand that ACTION_TIME_TICK has a fixed 1-minute interval that cannot be changed? And should AlarmManager be used with ACTION_TIME_TICK somehow, or is there maybe an example or link on how to use AlarmManager alone for the current purposes?